# Oracle 11g - SQL to Calculate time difference between several rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

**PROBLEM**

I'm still finding my feet with SQL and trying to calculate how long a certain user has been scanning items during their shift.

Each scan is timestamped generating a unique 9 digit sequence number (**SEQ** column) and date/time in the format `05-NOV-16 15:35:24` (**THE_DATE** column).

The person may be scanning for several hours, and what im trying to do is subtract the first timestamp they generated from the very last timestamp at the end of their shift.

So for example given this data sample:

```
+-----------+--------------------+--------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
|    SEQ    |      THE_DATE      | SCANID | LOCATN  | USER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
+-----------+--------------------+--------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 103939758 | 05-NOV-16 14:36:22 | 194972 | DOOR 19 | AX9868  | Mike       | Derry     |
| 103939780 | 05-NOV-16 14:38:07 | 194972 | DOOR 19 | AX9868  | Mike       | Derry     |
| 103939792 | 05-NOV-16 14:39:24 | 194972 | DOOR 19 | AX9868  | Mike       | Derry     |
| 103940184 | 05-NOV-16 15:16:53 | 194972 | DOOR 19 | AX9868  | Mike       | Derry     |
| 103940185 | 05-NOV-16 15:51:41 | 194972 | DOOR 19 | AX9868  | Mike       | Derry     |
| 103940214 | 05-NOV-16 09:51:42 | 194993 | DOOR 16 | BC1910  | Tony       | McCann    |
| 103940215 | 05-NOV-16 15:19:06 | 194993 | DOOR 16 | BC1910  | Tony       | McCann    |
|+-----------+--------------------+--------+---------+---------+------------------------
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

I would like to subtract the timestamp in the first row for Mike Derry, from the last row on which he appears, row 5 in this case, so that i have an answer in hours (1.25).

the final result should be grouped by day and by user_id,first_name and last_name.

So far i have looked online and at the oracle documentation ,which led me to try using the LEAD function which seemed promising. It looks at the next rows to find the next timestamp where a userid appears next and then partitions by this userid to create a new column with that timestamp.

So the SQL looked like this

```
SELECT SEQ, THE_DATE,SCANID,LOCATN,USER_ID,LEAD(SYSDAT ) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY SYSDAT) AS NEXT_SCAN 
FROM myTable...
```

However this is giving me incorrect results as it seems to double count the time difference. Im sure you SQL gurus have a more elegant way around this as i dont think this function suits this particular problem :)

*So the final result im trying to achieve is:*

```
+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| THE_DATE  | USER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | TOTAL_HRS |
+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 05-NOV-16 | AX9868  | Mike       | Derry     |      1.25 |
| 05-NOV-16 | BC1910  | Tony       | McCann    |      5.47 |
+-----------+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: what type is `THE_DATE` ? timestamp or varchar?

Comment: hi its a DATE type. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TRUNC(THE_DATE) as THE_DATE, USER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,
       MAX(THE_DATE) - MIN(THE_DATE) as TOTAL_HRS 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY TRUNC(THE_DATE), USER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
```

Comment: `to_date()` will produce weird (and often incorrect) results when applied to a date. Also, date differences in Oracle are in days and the OP needs it in hours. Also, this query will produce groups of exactly one row each from the input data.

Comment: @mathguy can you elaborate what you mean weird and incorrect result? I can check the result to convert to hours. But why you mean `one row`, Im group by `THE_DATE` and `USER_ID` so you should get one row for day and user.

Comment: `to_date()` takes a STRING argument and converts it to a date. If you pass it a DATE argument, it will convert it to string - using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings - and then convert it back to date. For example, if your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi', it will truncate seconds, etc. Then: the_date is distinct in all rows, so if you group by it, there will be no "groups" - each initial row will be in a different group.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You genius!! :) That worked ! I modified the code a little, instead of TO_DATE i had to use trunc(THE_DATE) and applied the ROUND function to the TOTAL_HRS . Thanks so much !

Comment: @Nick If you're looking for the date difference in hours, you'll need to multiply the difference by 24, since date differences are measured in terms of the number of days. i.e. `MAX(THE_DATE) - MIN(THE_DATE)` is number of days, `24 * (MAX(THE_DATE) - MIN(THE_DATE))` is number of hours. You may have already worked that out, but from Juan's answer it's not clear.

Comment: @Boneist . Yes i knew that from playing with the data on excel but your input is appreciated.thanks for your comment

Comment: @mathguy Thanks too for that. Its the very reason i had to try using trunc instead.

Answer (score 3):

Notes.... you shouldn't have redundant data (first name, last name) in this table, you should have a separate table just for that. It seems your hours are truncated and not rounded? (the rounding would give 1.26 in the first row).

```
with
     test_data ( seq, the_date, scanid, locatn, user_id, first_name, last_name ) as (
       select 103939758, to_date('05-NOV-16 14:36:22', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 194972, 'DOOR 19', 'AX9868', 'Mike', 'Derry'  from dual union all
       select 103939780, to_date('05-NOV-16 14:38:07', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 194972, 'DOOR 19', 'AX9868', 'Mike', 'Derry'  from dual union all
       select 103939792, to_date('05-NOV-16 14:39:24', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 194972, 'DOOR 19', 'AX9868', 'Mike', 'Derry'  from dual union all
       select 103940184, to_date('05-NOV-16 15:16:53', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 194972, 'DOOR 19', 'AX9868', 'Mike', 'Derry'  from dual union all
       select 103940185, to_date('05-NOV-16 15:51:41', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 194972, 'DOOR 19', 'AX9868', 'Mike', 'Derry'  from dual union all
       select 103940214, to_date('05-NOV-16 09:51:42', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 194993, 'DOOR 16', 'BC1910', 'Tony', 'McCann' from dual union all
       select 103940215, to_date('05-NOV-16 15:19:06', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 194993, 'DOOR 16', 'BC1910', 'Tony', 'McCann' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select trunc(the_date) as the_date, user_id, first_name, last_name,
       trunc(24 * (max(the_date) - min(the_date)), 2) as total_hrs
from   test_data
group by trunc(the_date), user_id, first_name, last_name
;

THE_DATE  USER_ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  TOTAL_HRS
--------- ------- ---------- --------- ----------
05-NOV-16 AX9868  Mike       Derry           1.25
05-NOV-16 BC1910  Tony       McCann          5.45
```

Comment: do you know how make oracle demo in [rextester](http://rextester.com/EZMHT42189) ?? I get some sintaxis error and cant make it work

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with rextester (or other online SQL query tools); for my own learning, I downloaded and installed a free version of Oracle directly on my machine.

Comment: OK, I may have to do that to test my queries.

Comment: hi, no i have never used that as not familiar with it. i shall take alook at it when i get home.PS: THE_DATE is showing as datatype DATE in my database and not TIMESTAMP if that helps. cheers

Comment: Using `WITH` sintaxis instead of `CREATE TABLE`  works ok http://rextester.com/IEGF66685

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, you can use [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - yes, when it works! I wanted to point Juan to the same, but the site wasn't working this morning   :-(