# Using lag to calculate difference between rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to determine the amount of time a part is sitting between when it is finished, and when its sale happens (trying to figure out if its in inventory for too long)

My data looks like below:

```
| SaleID | ProductFinished | ProductSold |
|:------:|:---------------:|:-----------:|
|   100  |     5/1/2019    |   6/1/2019  |
|   200  |     7/1/2019    |   7/3/2019  |
|   300  |    6/23/2019    |  6/30/2019  |
|   400  |    6/20/2019    |  6/21/2019  |
|   500  |    4/21/2019    |  5/21/2019  |
|   600  |    5/11/2019    |  6/20/2019  |
```

[And here is an SQL Fiddle with that table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bf850)

I need to calculate the difference between the current row's `ProductSold` value and the previous row's `ProductFinished` value, and then assign that difference to the `SittingTimer` column for the current row. My goal dataset looks like this:

```
| SaleID | ProductFinished | ProductSold | SittingTimer |
|:------:|:---------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|
|   100  |     5/1/2019    |   6/1/2019  |     NULL     |
|   200  |     7/1/2019    |   7/3/2019  |      63      |
|   300  |    6/23/2019    |  6/30/2019  |      -1      |
|   400  |    6/20/2019    |  6/21/2019  |      -2      |
|   500  |    4/21/2019    |  5/21/2019  |      -30     |
|   600  |    5/11/2019    |  6/20/2019  |      60      |
```

I have read up on [Oracle's `LAG` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm), and have seen some posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510334/oracle-11g-sql-to-calculate-time-difference-between-several-rows) that use `LAG`, but I can't seem to get it to work right.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
  tblSales.*,
  TO_NUMBER(LAG(ProductFinished - ProductSold, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY SaleID)) AS SittingTimer

 FROM
   tblSales
```

But got this for results:

```
SALEID  PRODUCTFINISHED     PRODUCTSOLD     SITTINGTIMER
100     2019-04-30T00:00:00Z    2019-05-31T00:00:00Z    0
200     2019-06-30T00:00:00Z    2019-07-02T00:00:00Z    -31
300     2019-06-22T00:00:00Z    2019-06-29T00:00:00Z    -2
400     2019-06-19T00:00:00Z    2019-06-20T00:00:00Z    -7
500     2019-04-20T00:00:00Z    2019-05-20T00:00:00Z    -1
600     2019-05-10T00:00:00Z    2019-06-19T00:00:00Z    -30
```

Where am I going wrong? Should I avoid using `LAG`?

Comment: Your question and fiddle seem confused about the column names (quoted or not?) and data types (dates or timestamps?)

Comment: I think I removed the quotes and didn't update the original fiddle. The data was automatically made into a timestamp by `SQLFIDDLE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be subtracting the current row's value from the lag result; not subtracting within the lag function:

```
SELECT
  tblSales.*,
  LAG("ProductFinished", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "SaleID") - "ProductSold" AS SittingTimer

 FROM
   tblSales;

    SaleID ProductFinished         ProductSold             SITTINGTIMER
---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------
       100 30-Apr-2019 08:00:00 PM 31-May-2019 08:00:00 PM             
       200 30-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM 02-Jul-2019 08:00:00 PM          -63
       300 22-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM 29-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM            1
       400 19-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM 20-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM            2
       500 20-Apr-2019 08:00:00 PM 20-May-2019 08:00:00 PM           30
       600 10-May-2019 08:00:00 PM 19-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM          -60

6 rows selected.
```

That gives you "difference between the current row's ProductSold value and the previous row's ProductFinished value"; to swap the sign of those values change the order the values are subtracted:

```
SELECT
  tblSales.*,
  "ProductSold" - LAG("ProductFinished", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "SaleID") AS SittingTimer

 FROM
   tblSales;

    SaleID ProductFinished         ProductSold             SITTINGTIMER
---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------
       100 30-Apr-2019 08:00:00 PM 31-May-2019 08:00:00 PM             
       200 30-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM 02-Jul-2019 08:00:00 PM           63
       300 22-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM 29-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM           -1
       400 19-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM 20-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM           -2
       500 20-Apr-2019 08:00:00 PM 20-May-2019 08:00:00 PM          -30
       600 10-May-2019 08:00:00 PM 19-Jun-2019 08:00:00 PM           60
```

It also assumes your columns are dates rather than timestamps - since your query would error with ORA-00932 if they were timestamps; but I kept the quoted identifiers from your SQL Fiddle anyway, on the basis they must be there for a reason. (It is confusing for your question data and query to not match your fiddle...)

Answer (score 2):

use below query, you need `lead()` analytic function

```
SELECT
  tblSales.*, lead("ProductSold") over(order by "SaleID")-"ProductFinished" as  prf 

 FROM
   tblSales
```

output

```
SaleID  ProductFinished     ProductSold                SITTINGTIMER
100     2019-04-30 20:00:00.0   2019-05-31 20:00:00.0   63 0:0:0.0
200     2019-06-30 20:00:00.0   2019-07-02 20:00:00.0   -1 0:0:0.0
300     2019-06-22 20:00:00.0   2019-06-29 20:00:00.0   -2 0:0:0.0
400     2019-06-19 20:00:00.0   2019-06-20 20:00:00.0   -30 0:0:0.0
500     2019-04-20 20:00:00.0   2019-05-20 20:00:00.0   60 0:0:0.0
600     2019-05-10 20:00:00.0   2019-06-19 20:00:00.0   (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using timestamp then you need to use extract day from timestamp to find the desired result like the following:

```
SELECT
    "SaleID",
    "ProductFinished",
    "ProductSold",
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM "ProductSold" - LAG("ProductFinished") OVER(
        ORDER BY
            "SaleID"
    )) AS SITTINGTIMER
FROM
    TBLSALES
```

Output:

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c2cfcd1785dd637a9f522ed73a493b40)

Cheers!!